# Would plugging a 1M resistor into the outlet be bad?

Tags: resistors

Other then touching the leads and getting shocked, if I plug a 1M, 0.5W resistor into the 120V outlet, would it be bad?

I calculated that \$\frac{120 V}{1 M\Omega} = 0.12 mA\$, which shouldn't do anything bad if only 0.12 mA is going through, but I don't know if AC is different or something.

Comment: This can work. Your resistor gets heated with 14mW (120V^2/1MOhm). That's all. But I don't think it's a real save or good way to prevent a touching. If you touch the legs of the resistor, it would have the same effect than touching the leads!

Comment: Define 'bad'. You would risk your life and consume needless power. How bad does bad have to be?

Comment: I'll use a needle nose pliers and will make sure I  dont touch it and put a hand behind my back

Comment: Better use a switch on some distance instead.

Comment: Yeah good plan.

Comment: If I have a distant switch, might as well put a 1 ohm reaistor

Comment: Am I going to be the only person to ask *why* you're sticking a resistor into the AC outlet?

Comment: Idk I'm bored!!

Comment: I don't like to sound like a patronizing old guy, but I used to do things like that at your age - and I had several nasty shocks as a result. Quite honestly I'm lucky to be alive now. Eventually I became a professional engineer instead of trying to kill myself!

Comment: It's not like I'm going to touch the leads or anything

Comment: Geesh @Mike, you sound like a patronizing old guy.  It's really not hard to do this safely, and 1 MOhm won't be all that exciting.  I learned some interesting stuff plugging things into outlets.  I usually used the distance switch or breaker or fuse method.  I was wondering why there was always a resistor in series with neon bulbs, so I tried it without.  The most spectacular was a carbon mic from a old phone.  That shot out a really pretty orange flame about two feet.

Comment: cool, so how many ohms should I have it just enough to get hot and do fun stuff, but not so little that nothing happens/ it burns out too fast

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, you've basically got the right idea except for the units in your calculation being off.  120V / 1MΩ = 120µA.  That's very little.  The more relevant calculation is how much power the resistor will dissipate.  That is the voltage accross it times the current thru it.  By Ohm's law you can rearrange those equations to realize that is also the square of the voltage accross it divided by the resistance:

(120V)<sup>2</sup> / 1MΩ = 14.4 mW

That's again very little.  You probably wouldn't even notice that getting warm if you touched it, although in this case touching it would be a bad idea due to the high voltage accross the two leads.

Note that since 120 V is the RMS voltage, that is the equivalent DC voltage that will deliver the same power, so the above is correct and would also work identically with 120 V DC.

However, there is one additional wrinkle with AC, which is the peak voltage the resistor can withstand.  That does NOT average out since insulation breaks down with instantaneous voltage regardless of what the average over some time might be.  Since the 120 V RMS is a sine, the peaks are sqrt(2) higher, which is 170 V. The resistor needs to be rated for at least that much voltage, else its insulation might break or it might arc between the leads.

Answer (score 2):

If your outlet is 120V AC, you have correctly calculated the current in the 1M resistor. You calculate it as if it were DC but, bear in mind, that AC specified as being 120 V actually peaks 1.414 times as high, at nearly 170 V<sub>pk</sub>.

For rating powers and calculating currents in resistors this is fine, but you'll need to use the peak voltage if it were a capacitor you were trying to use, since one of the failure modes of capacitors is over-voltage.